# WPF MVVM: MainWindow navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, contentcontrol

I have a WPF application that contains one window. Only throw this window the user can perform his navigation in the app.

The application structure is:

- MainWindow.xaml
- MainWindowViewModel.cs
- StartPage.xaml
- StartPageViewMode.cs
- Systems.xaml
- Systems.cs
- Another views and related view models.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
   <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentWorkspace}" x:Name="ContentControlMainWindow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
private ContentControl _currentWorkspace;
public ContentControl CurrentWorkspace
{
     get => _currentWorkspace;
     set => SetProperty(ref _currentWorkspace, value);
}

//c'tor
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   CurrentWorkspace.Content = new ContentControl { Content = new StartPage() 
}
```

As you can see, at the application initialization i'm loading the StartPage view to the CurrentWorkspace. 
Now from the StartPageViewModel i need to change the CurrentWorkspace content to another view.
Basically i'm having struggle to control (and change) this CurrentWorkspace from each part of the application.

Comment: See navigation concepts in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I like this kind of approach:

In MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
// You would more likely type this as something like ViewModelBase/ObservableObject/etc.
private object _currentWorkspace;
public object CurrentWorkspace
{
    get => _currentWorkspace;
    set => SetProperty(ref _currentWorkspace, value);
}

private StartPageViewModel _startPageViewModel;
public StartPageViewModel StartPageViewModel
{
    get => _startPageViewModel;
    set => SetProperty(ref _startPageViewModel, value);
}

private AnotherPageViewModel _anotherPageViewModel;
public AnotherPageViewModel AnotherPageViewModel
{
    get => _anotherPageViewModel;
    set => SetProperty(ref _anotherPageViewModel, value);
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{   
    StartPageViewModel = new StartPageViewModel();
    AnotherPageViewModel = new AnotherPageViewModel();

    CurrentWorkspace = StartPageViewModel;
}

// Navigation Method
private void NavigateToStartPage()
{
    if (CurrentWorkspace != StartPageViewModel)
        CurrentWorkspace = StartPageViewModel;
}

// Navigation Method
private void NavigateToAnotherPage()
{
    if (CurrentWorkspace != AnotherPageViewModel)
        CurrentWorkspace = AnotherPageViewModel;
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:App.Views"
    ... >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControlMainWindow"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentWorkspace}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="start_page_view"
                              DataType="{x:Type vm:StartPageViewModel}">
                    <vw:StartPage />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="another_page_view"
                              DataType="{x:Type vm:AnotherPageViewModel}">
                    <vw:AnotherPage />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window/>
```

You can then set `CurrentWorkspace` to whatever you want. If you want to dispose of the instance of `StartPageViewModel` for example, you can just set `StartPageViewModel = null;`.

It's generally regarded as a violation of MVVM to have UI elements, e.g., `ContentControl`, in your ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I still don't understand how can I change the current workspace from different view model (who is not the main window view model)?

Comment: I've added another property as well as two navigation methods that will hopefully explain this - it's then a question of calling these methods on `MainWindowViewModel`, typically via some kind of `ICommand`. Let me know if this explains it.